# How to move ".android" folder in win 10 to another place?

Tags: windows, android-studio

.android folder is keeping recteating inside user folder.
I saw tip about setting AnDROID_SDK_HOME but it is deprecated and variable is removed as soon as I start  studio.
Sdk is located at E:\programms\androidsdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ANDROID_HOME` is supposed to be deprecated, not `ANDROID_SDK_HOME`. Testing on Android Studio 4.0.1, the environment variable `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` is honored and works correctly.

Ensure you are setting the environment variable properly as a user variable on Windows 10:
`Start -> Edit the system environment variables -> Environment Variables -> User variables for <username>`

---

An alternative solution (if the above is not working) is to use symbolic links, of which there are two methods (both accomplishing the same goal):

- CMD: Using Windows Command Prompt, which may require Administrator privileges

```
mklink /D E:\Android\.android C:\Users\<username>\.android
```

- GUI: [Link Shell Extension](https://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html)

This will effectively enable you to store your `.android` folder at `E:\Android\.android`, but still support applications referencing `C:\Users\<username>\.android`. Note that some applications may encounter issues with symbolic links; your mileage may vary.